# Javascript variable is not accessible in chrome but works fine in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, variables, firefox

I have a variable in javascript file, I want to access that variable using script tag in my html file. When I print that variable in console then it works fine in firefox but in chrome it says the variable is undefined.

Here is my code -

abc.js

```
var a ="This is a variable";
```

index.html

```
<script src="abc.js"></script>
<script>console.log(a);</script>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your variable scope in JavaScript. If you declared it inside a function it will not work as it will be a local variable. Following code works both in Firefox and Chrome for variable a and not for b.

SO20151211.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Stack Overflow</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="SO20151211.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(a);
    document.write(b);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

SO20151211.js

```
var a="This is variable A";
function myFunc() {
    var b="This is variable B";
}
```

Comment: I have also written the same kind of code. But still it doesn't work in chrome. I really don't understand the reason. In mozilla, its working fine. I have not defined variable inside any function.

Comment: @sajalsuraj mind posting your solution here? Sorry for resurrecting this question.